# How to rewrite any url that doesn't match a specific pattern

Tags: .htaccess

I want to rewrite any url that doesn't match the pattern `*.php`

Example: `domain.com/abc.html` or `domain.com/abc`  should be rewritten to  `domain.com/abc.php`

Answer (score 0):

For rewriting .html extensions to existing .php files with the same name, try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: I know this. But I want negative condition.  if doesn't match with *.php, then rewrite. Given url can be anything, .html, .htm, .xyz, etc

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick solution:

```
if len(url.split('.php'))==1: 
    extention = '.' + (url.split('.')[-1]) 
    url = url.replace(extention,'.php')
```

But not a good practice to do this way